# Does partition size on SSD affect speed

Tags: partitioning, ssd, performance

SSD speeds depend mostly on the size of a specific drive.

So lets say if a single chip on SSD has 256GB and gives 256MB/s (R/W) speed,
then a drive made of 4 chips would have 1TB capacity and 1GB/s speed,
a drive made of 8 chips would have 2TB capacity and 2GB/s speed
and so on.

Now lets assume I took such a 2TB (8 chips) drive and split it into 8 equal partitions (256GB each).
Now if I will be performing writes into only a single partition,
will I be limited to 256MB/s, or will I be able to utilize the full 2GB/s speed?

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted other than stating an incorrect fact and asking a question about it. That, in my opinion should not warrant a downvote, only a good answer. Luckily that was provided. I'm going to vote this question up for that reason. That said, the only speed issues with an SSD is defragmentation. If a drive becomes too full, then the speeds will drop. Its not about the total size of the drive, but rather how well the drive can TRIM once its becoming full.

Comment: @LPChip Fragmentation on a drive refers to data logically sequential (same file, or files used frequently together) being separated on the platters of the drive requiring higher seek times. SSDs don't store or read data in the same way and fragmentation is not really a concern on SSDs for this reason. TRIM is about emptying the current deleted-but-not-cleared bits in order to speed subsequent writes, as individual bits on an SSD must be erased before they can be rewritten.

Comment: @music2myear yes, I know how SSD's work. I'm talking about how too little free space can cause TRIM to not be able to mark entire clusters as free, causing fragmentation on an SSD. If you are unfamiliar with fragmentation on SSD's, please do some research. It is a real issue that exists. Most expensive SSD's have extra space that you can't see to prevent fragmentation from happening, but if you get the SSD full to 0 bytes left, the SSD will be extremely slow due to fragmentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SSD speeds depend mostly on the size of a specific drive

It really isn't, though.

The physical structure the memory uses, the controller specs, and other factors are also involved, and have a more substantial impact on the speed of the drive.

Further, with an SSD you don't have access to the physical structure in the way you'd need to take advantage of any such partition/structure mapping.

Both practically and theoretically you are incorrect.